# Ora-30036 Ora-06512 and Ora-04088

Tags: sql, import, oracle11g, oracle-sqldeveloper

Hi I am uploading a 6GB csv file in oracle. My tablespace has capacity of 100GB but i get error in it.

> ORA-30036: unable to extend segment by 8 in undo tablespace 'UNDOTBS1'.
>   ORA-06512: at "user.Trigger", line 4.
>   ORA-04088 error during execution of trigger.

I dont what is the error it shows 3Error here what i have to do now?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This error means that you have run out of space in your UNDO tablespace. The UNDO tablespace is what keeps track of changes to the data (deletes, inserts, updates, etc) so that a) they can be rolled back if you perform a rollback, and b) so that other sessions see data as it was before your session started messing around with it.

You will need to contact your DBAs and get that tablespace extended, or alternatively (but not recommended, especially if this is an oft-run process), break up the transaction into smaller blocks.

Extending the tablespace would be the way I'd go.

Comment: But My table tablespace is different. So if i increase the UNDO tablespace it will work?and what about Trigger error it is coming by UNDO tablespace.

Comment: Yes, your database objects will live in a tablespace that you (or the DBA) has created specifically to hold them. There are two tablespaces that must be created that aren't related to a specific schema - these are the UNDO and the TEMP tablespaces. I highly recommend you research these. The UNDO tablespace needs to be sized to the biggest transaction that will be run, otherwise you'll end up running out of space - which is the error that you've experienced.

Comment: Say, for example, you try to update 10,000 records, but your UNDO tablespace only has room to hold information about 9000 rows of changes; what happens to the other 1000 rows in your update statement? Clearly Oracle can't go ahead and make the changes because if you were to rollback, how would it know what to roll those 1000 rows back to? So, it fails the whole operation. If you want to update those rows, you need to make sure you have enough space in the UNDO to hold information about the changes to all 10,000 rows, plus the information for any other active transactions, etc.

Comment: So currently my csv file is 6GB and I want to insert in mytablespace which is 100GB but my UNDO tablespace is about 1GB . So how much i should increase the size of UNDO tablespace. and this is insert operation and there is nothing in my table now.

Comment: You'd have to increase it and see; You could go with 6GB initially, but there's no harm in increasing it more (except unused space is wasted space of course, but if your server has plenty of space available, this may not be such an issue). You could also set it to auto-extend, such that it will grow as big as it needs to. This could be a good or a bad thing, so depending on your situation, you may want to do that temporarily to see how large it grows, and then revert to a fixed size.